# Remind me why I'm bountying this question?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bounty-dialog

When I'm writing the custom reason for a bounty, especially because of my poor working memory, I'd really appreciate to be reminded of the reason *and phrasing* of the bounty reason.

There choice I make here:

[image: The dialog presented when starting a bounty, providing a variety of reasons]

Is not reflected here:

[image: optional custom message input box]

I mainly came across this as I wanted to reuse the phrasing and say 'X is no longer an authoritative ...' and I didn't remember how the reason was phrased. Source? Reference? I went and checked, and filled in the blank.

A reminder would be nice though.

Comment: It looks like the custom message would override the default text too. (I don't think it does.)

Comment: Workaround: Just open another tab to view the first page of the dialog. However, that a workaround exists doesn't mean that the UI shouldn't be changed to display the selected option in the second page of the dialog.

Comment: @Makyen you can just click 'back', but it's still an extra two clicks (and no guarantee I'll remember between clicks)

Comment: There is a more fundamental problem with the design of the bounty dialogs; I can never predict what actually ends up being displayed in the bounty notice. Adding a preview step at the end, obviously with the option to go back and change one of the previous steps, would fix the broader problem I hope.